# How to apply speedsettings to AGV and it's loaded Agent?

Tags: anylogic

Source produces Agent `Seat`. By Crane `Seat` moves to node `loadingPoint`. An AGV gets to this node and seizes`Seat`, than moves pathguided trough several Point Nodes. To set different speeds between the Point Nodes I tried block `Move To` from Point Node to Point Node. Now I am confused with the agent Type you have to set under "advanced" in this block. I want my AGV to change it's speed, but when choosing AGV as Agent type in the `Move To` block it generates an error. When I choose `Seat` the model runs but then `Seat` and AGV get seperated and `Seat` is moving alone. I don´t understand how to apply my speed settings for the AGV AND for it's transported Agent `Seat`. Is the Move To Block just for normal Agents and not for Transporters as my AGV?